# MS Access 2003 - SUM Function

Tags: ms-access, sum

How do you calculate with code the SUM of a row of data instead of a column of data?

Answer (score 2):

There is no function for this one, you would have to do something like:

```
select col1, col2, col3, (nz(col1,0)+nz(col2,0)+nz(col3,0)) as Sum from Table
```

Comment: Watch out for nulls. 1+Null+1=Null. You can use Nz to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
  Public Function iSum(ParamArray p()) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngUBound As Long
    Dim v As Variant

    v = Nz(p(LBound(p)), 0)
    lngUBound = UBound(p)
    For i = LBound(p) + 1 To lngUBound
      If Not IsNull(p(i)) Then
         v = v + p(i)
      End If
    Next
    If IsNull(v) Then
       v = 0
    End If
    iSum = v
  End Function
```

And in SQL:

```
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, iSum(col1,col2,col3) As Sum 
  FROM Table
```

You can pass any number of columns, and it doesn't matter if any of them are Null. If all are Null, it returns 0.

Comment: Bascially, what i have is 5 column headings with information in each column and 5 row headings with info in each row, so its a table of info,,,,so how do i take the "info" in each column but only from row 1 and have it placed in a new seperate cell by itself??

Comment: @HansUp: you're right about that. I've altered the code to address that.

Comment: @Jeff Anderson: it seems to me that @Remou's answer does the job, as would mind. Maybe you haven't properly explained the context, because both answers look to me to completely solve the question as you asked it.